# Spark mapPartitions iterator returns duplicate records

Tags: java, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I am having an implementation class for FlatMapFunction>>, String>. Initialising some non-serialisable connections for each partition. But when I call next() on the iterator, it gives same record for multiple partitions. Following is the code:

```
@Override
    public Iterator < String > call(Iterator < Tuple2 < String, Iterable < String >>> tuple2Iterator)
    throws Exception {
        BitLambdaService lambda = buildClient();
        List <String> resultList = new ArrayList < > ();
        while (tuple2Iterator.hasNext()) {
            Tuple2 < String, Iterable < String >> tpl = tuple2Iterator.next();
            // do something
        }
        return resultList.iterator();
    }
```

Does anyone faced this problem earlier? Or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by calling the `rdd.cache()` just after the transformation. The problem occured because the transformations are executed in lazy fashion, and when an action is applied on RDD, the transformations are actually executed when a action is applied on RDD. So the mapPartitions was not waiting for the call method to complete and assigned the same records to another executor.